# display none on flickity-slides not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, flickity

I would like to know if adding the .is-visible and .is-hidden dynamically still makes the added classes visible to flickity.
I dynamically add using $('[data-thumbnail-color],[data-image-color]').removeClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden'); to the list items that respectively need to be hidden or visible; buy when add cellSelector: '.carousel-cell.is-visible'; the carousel disappears.

display none on flickity-slides doesnt make them none-items.
want to skip the display:none item when some when click on next previous button

Comment: What means *"images funality"*? Any code to share? Please [edit] with a [mcve]. Read [ask].

Comment: I would like to know if adding the .is-visible and .is-hidden dynamically still makes the added classes visible to flickity. I dynamically add using $('[data-thumbnail-color],[data-image-color]').removeClass('is-visible').removeClass('is-hidden'); to the list items that respectively need to be hidden or visible; buy when add cellSelector: '.carousel-cell.is-visible'; the carousel disappears.